# How to Restrict Default User Permissions for New Public Sites in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, site, read-only

SharePoint Online admin here. In our organization there are several thousand users and even more SPO sites. We are trying to tackle challenges with site permissions that potentially expose us to risks from insider threats, while still allowing users to create new SPO sites.

By default, when a user creates a new site, the "Site members" group is set to include "Everyone except external users," which grants write/edit/delete/add new members permissions across these sites.

At the moment we check all public sites manually, but it's quite time-consuming...

**My question: is there a way to automatically:**

- **Prevent users from creating new public sites altogether**, or
- **Ensure that new sites automatically assign "Everyone except external users" to the "Site visitors" group instead of "Site members," thereby granting read-only access by default?**

Has anyone implemented a similar permission model or restriction in their organization? Could you provide guidance (possibly PowerShell scripts) that could enforce these settings?

Any advice on best practices for managing such a scenario in would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can restrict users from creating "any" kind of sites by following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-creation. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for...we'd like to find a middle ground between "total ban" and "free for all" for new SPO sites.

Comment: @MikeK. Are you looking for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/restricted-access-control
You can leverage a site creation approval process or use sensitivity labels. Or: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps
Using PowerShell: `Set-SPOSite -Identity <siteurl> -RestrictedAccessControl $true`

Comment: @MartinIszac Thanks, I'll go throught the documentation. 
From the 2 things you are suggesting, sensitivity labels sound more promising than site creation approval process, as the current admin x user ratio in our org doesn't allow us to deal with individual sites.